# Can't make footer stick to the bottom of the page

Tags: html, css, footer, sticky-footer

smiths-heimann.az is my website. tried all instructions from http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/ But it doesn't work for me (proof that it doesn't work http://smiths-heimann.az/?page=3). Please help me to make stick footer to the bottom of the page and remove empty line between 2 divs http://prntscr.com/2e2fp  Thx in advance

Comment: The proof won't load, at least not for me. Can you post your basic HTML structure along with CSS?

Comment: oh sorry. try this link http://smiths-heimann.az?page=3

Comment: I've edited your post to have the new URL.

Comment: @Hristo are you there? smiths-heimann.az/?page=3 please check for wrong code. i'm still getting the gap between container and footer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `#footer` is inside `#wrap`. The sticky footer code has the footer *outside* `#wrap`:

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="main">
        <div id="content">
        </div>
        <div id="side">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="footer">
</div>
```

**Edit**

Just had a look at your site with the moved footer code. You've got a gap at the bottom which, if you don't want it, can be solved by making the `#footer`'s `height` the same as the footer's `margin-top`, but positive.

**Edit to other problem**

Inside your header, you have a navigation `ul` with a few classes: `sf-menu`, `sf-js-enabled` and `sf-shadow`. If you take `margin-bottom: 1em` off that, the gap is removed.

**Edit to non-stretching background problem**

This is still quite simple, although it will change the header's transparency a little.

Find the `background-image` for `#container` in your CSS file and move it to `#wrap`. To clarify, `#wrap` should have this CSS:

```
#wrap 
{
    min-height: 100%;
    background: url("img/tff.png") 0 0 repeat;
}
```

And `#container` should look like this:

```
#container 
{
    min-width: 980px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    padding-bottom: 110px;
}
```

**Second edit to non-stretching background problem**

Ok. Whew. I did it; I removed the scrollbar too.

Make `#footer` be:

```
#footer {
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , #FFFFFF, #EEEEEE) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    border-top: 1px solid #919191;
    clear: both;
    font-size: 10px;
    height: 110px;
    margin-top: -126px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
```

The scroll bar was appearing because borders and padding *add extra height* to the footer, so the negative margin was actually too small. I've changed it to `-116px`. *While this works in Firefox, the OP found out it does not work in Chrome*. Eventually, an edited image was used to get the functionality required. Only use this answer as a reference.

Now make `#wrap` this:

```
#wrap {
    background: url("img/tff.png") repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    height: auto;
    margin-top: 100px;
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
```

Finally, make `.header` this:

```
.header {
    background-image: url("img/nav/trans.png");
    color: white;
    height: 80px;
    top: -100px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative
}
```

Comment: changed and uploaded. http://smiths-heimann.az/?page=3 try this one. Something else wrong with css and new empty lines appeared between divs http://prntscr.com/2e2fp

Comment: @Tural... that's because you have `margin-top: -150px;` on the footer. It should be the height of the footer + other miscellaneous heights, like from borders.

Comment: changed. still no success. try link above once more

Comment: Have you read the *Edit to other problem* bit in my answer? I can still see the `margin-bottom` on your `ul`.

Comment: @Tural... + other miscellaneous heights/margins/paddings. As JamWaffles mentioned, you have the 1em margin-bottom...

Comment: @Tural: Moar editz! Have a look at **Edit to non-stretching background problem** in my answer.

Comment: @JamWaffles How can i seperate header part from wrap? second bg (the last modification) changes all the look of my website

Comment: I take it you want the translucent white to stretch all the way to the footer? I fixed it for that issue. Can you explain (or show us by updating your live code in your link) so we know what's going on?

Comment: No problem. For others with a similar question, possibly, I'll post any solutions up here as an edit.

Answer (score 0):

```
 margin-top: -150px;
```

lose that CSS

Comment: -1 a) If you're talking about `#footer`, it's supposed to be there and b) It's ambiguous which `margin` you're talking about. Please do your research before posting an answer. http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/using-sticky-footer-code.html

Comment: OK, I guess I deserve the -1 then:) Of course not remove the entire #footer, it is needed, but just the margin-top. Btw, I did visit the site and used firebug to disable that CSS before posting my answer.

Comment: I was rather brash, I do admit. I downvoted because the sticky footer tutorial specifically sets the negative margin. At least I gave a reason to downvote, eh :-)

Comment: ah, thanks for explaining, I just needed further research. Hey SO is place to learn stuff.

Comment: http://smiths-heimann.az/?page=3 please check for wrong code. i'm still getting the gap between container and footer

Comment: SO is definitely a great place to learn things. Judging by your rep, you don't need tell this, but I'll say it anyway: don't be dissuaded by the odd downvote.